# Scrollbar set to bottom on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a message Div where messages display as they are sent using ajax. the div has scroll bar but is set to the top. I created a simple function that would set it to the bottom. The script works if I click a button however it wont work on load

I've tried 2 things

```
<script>
    function ScrollBarBottom() {
      var msgDiv = document.getElementById("msg-body");
      msgDiv.scrollTop = msgDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
  </script>
  <div class="msg-body" id="msg-body" onload="ScrollBarBottom()">
    <!-- Message Will Be Added Here From AJAX -->
  </div>
```

2

```
function ScrollBarBottom() {
      var msgDiv = document.getElementById("msg-body");
      msgDiv.scrollTop = msgDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ScrollBarBottom();
    });
```

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` did u try this?

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this, Hope this works for you too**

```
$("#msg-body").show()[0].scrollIntoView(false);
```